# remove element of prop in jointJS

Tags: javascript, jointjs

This is how I could add in jointJS an attribute or remove it if `content` is empty. Therefore I use `removeAttr`:

```
if (content) graph.getCell(cellId).attr('info/content', content);
else graph.getCell(cellId).removeAttr('info/content');
```

But for custom fields I want to use `prop()` (http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Element:prop). But there is no `removeProp` function to remove a field if the variable is empty:

```
if (content) graph.getCell(cellId).prop('data/info', content);
else graph.getCell(cellId).prop('data/info', '');
```

So how do I remove an element of `prop`?